# Why I get ERROR 1064 (42000) when I try to compare 2 characters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to compare to characters using MySQL. I've tried this tow querys:

```
ASCII(SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,1,1) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='prac' AND table_name='Users' limit 1)>0;
```

```
(SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,1,1) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='prac' AND table_name='Users' limit 1 )like 'A%';
```

But both of them give me this error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
```

If I execute the query without the comparation, like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,1,1) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='prac' AND table_name='Users' limit 1;
```

It returns the first letter from the column name without problems.

Why when I try to compare it with the character or the ASCII value I get that error?

Comment: What do you want to do there? Please explain the goal of your query.

Comment: I want to comprare 2 characters, and if there are equal return true, if not return false